# C++ flowchart from cod in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to generate a flowchart in Visual Studio 2019(project migrated from VC++ 6.0) or in a freeware/open source application just like [Visustin][1] does. I can't pay a license and I exceed the limit of files of the free service that they offer.

I've tried to generate it in codemap, but as yet without much success. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not a flow chart, but you can generate call graph (provided you can run gdb on the binary) : https://github.com/tarun27sh/gdb_graphs

Comment: As I know, create and edit code maps are [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2019#prerequisites) in Visual Studio Enterprise edition only, and it is not supported for Community and Professional editions. Are you using Enterprise edition?

Comment: Sure, VS Enterprise 2019. Thx!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.